# while loop with vector condition

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, do-while

I want to create a **while** loop which stops when one column equals to another (by element) but I got the following error:

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

For example:

```
y<-c(1,1)
z<-c(1,1)
x<-c(3,3)
while(y!=x){y=y+z}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close, just add an all statement to use the whole vector for the loop. Try looking at `?any` and `?all` for future vector by vector logical operations.

`while(all(x != y)) {y <- y + z}`